# Chinese characters showing as blank boxes in strings.xml

Tags: utf-8, localizable.strings, chinese-locale

I am trying to cut and paste traditional Chinese characters as alternative resources in my values-zh-rTW/strings.xml file.  They show as blank white boxes.  As far as I can find, every encoding option is set to UTF-8.  If it is a font issue, I'm not sure where to change the font or which font to change.  I did go to General>Appearance>Colors and Fonts, but I'm not sure which font to adjust, if any.  Please help if you've dealt with this before.

Comment: What program are you using to view them?

Comment: I am copying into Eclipse from a Google Drive document, with arial font.

Comment: When I copy the white boxes from Eclipse and paste somewhere else, such as the Google Search field or a Drive document, the Chinese is displayed properly again.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at this question to make sure you're doing everything mentioned here:

[How to support UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-in-eclipse)

Here's another question that may have what you need:

[How to print [Simplified] Chinese characters to Eclipse console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056900/how-to-print-simplified-chinese-characters-to-eclipse-console)

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: Hate to sound like the typical tech help guy, but have you restarted Eclipse since changing the settings?  Eclipse can be fickle sometimes with restarts.

Comment: I have text file encoding set to UTF-8 in preferences>general>workspace.  I have everything under preferences>general>Content Types set to UTF-8.  I have a language pack that includes Chinese, but I haven't figured out how to install it or if it is needed.  I had Chinese working fine in another installation of Eclipse without requiring any additional language packs.  Is there another UTF-8 setting or a specific font change that anyone is aware of?

Comment: I guess another question I have is whether the Chinese may still show up in the application when compiled even if they are displayed as blank squares in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution was to install "East Asian Languages" in windows. Just go to control panel, Regional and Language Options, Languages tab, and then check Install files for East Asian languages (it required a windows cd for me).

Answer (score 0):

There are some chinese characters in my eclipse editor. And it's not displayed correctly.
I change the project's text file coding by `Cmd + I` to show the project's Properties setting dialog. then in in put **GBK** in `Text file encoding`. then Apply it. the characters displayed correctly.

The screenshot is as below:
[image]