# Run java program with chinese arguments in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I input some arguments likes -D你好=你好, and invoke a single class ,

the java file as follows:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(String name :args){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

}

print results：

```
-D??=??
```

how could fix this issue?

Comment: See if those two links help : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console/  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056900/how-to-print-simplified-chinese-characters-to-eclipse-console

Comment: Have you tryed this?
[How to print [Simplified] Chinese characters to Eclipse console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056900/how-to-print-simplified-chinese-characters-to-eclipse-console) or [How to support UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse)

Comment: The console could show correct Chinese characters and project , java file, common encoding in debug configurations all seted UTF-8 , but strange , why setting  chinese character in program arguments view, the main method get the args couldn't show correct.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a clean way is not possible :
[Passing command line unicode argument to Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660651/passing-command-line-unicode-argument-to-java-code)

> Unfortunately you cannot reliably use non-ASCII characters with
>   command-line apps that use the Windows C runtime's stdlib, like Java
>   (and pretty much all non-Windows-specific scripting languages really).
>
> This is because they read their input and output using a
>   locale-specific code page by default, which is never a UTF, unlike
>   every other modern OS which uses UTF-8.
>
> Whilst you can change the code page of a terminal to something else
>   using the chcp command, the support for the UTF-8 encoding under chcp
>   65001 is broken in a few ways that are likely to trip apps up fatally.
>
> If you only need Japanese you could switch to code page 932 (similar
>   to Shift-JIS) by setting your locale (‘language for non-Unicode
>   applications’ in the Regional settings) to Japan. This will still fail
>   for characters that aren't in that code page though.
>
> If you need to get non-ASCII characters through the command line
>   reliably on Windows, you need to call the Win32 API function
>   GetCommandLineW directly to avoid the encode-to-system-code-page
>   layer. Probably you'd want to do that using JNA.